# Combine mesh and animation from two FBX files

Tags: animation, mesh, import, .fbx

I am new to Blender and I am trying to import this FBX model https://drive.google.com/file/d/167NCzF8Dv8aILrzon_drcBeV7DS1_bVE/view?usp=drivesdk from Unity Store https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/3d/characters/humanoids/polite-soldier-29807 to edit some animations.

But the problem is that there are several FBX files:

- `Characters\Soldier\Soldier.fbx` contains model (mesh, etc.) without animations.
- Files in `Animations\` (such as `Run_Rifle.FBX`) have animation but no mesh, that is I see only bones.

[image]

Is there any way to combine them? Animating without seeing the model is difficult. :)

I found some answers about selecting them and `Ctrl+J` (`Join`) but it doesn't work, the second object bones (animated) still remain separate.

Comment: Animations are not limited to any specific armature, so you can just select the Armature that the soldier is parented to and edit the all the animations using it.

Comment: @kheetor yeah, that makes sense, but I can't find how to do it :( https://i.gyazo.com/10e70e23fcaea39e9bcb404f2909756c.mp4